# How to convert Linux Vm with VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I am running VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone version 6.1.1 on Win7 sp1, and want to convert some Linux boxes, Ubuntu Desktop and Server 16.04...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009153) VMware knowledge base?

Comment: That is not the same problem. I tried this one and nothing https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008164

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone ends up here:
You must remove "Defaults requiretty" from sudoers to allow remote sudo commands execution without a real tty open.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008164

Comment: Could you add some reference to this answer supporting what you state as well and in addition to the source link?